# EJB implementing an interface from external library

Tags: java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I have a java class which implements an interface from an external library.
I converted this java class into an EJB by anotating with `@Stateless`.
The reason I converted this to an EJB is for leveraging the dependency injection and to get an handle for `EntityManager` API. But I am not able to inject this Stateless bean into other EJBs.

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to annotate your EJB with `@Stateless` and `@Local` too? It should contain the name of the interface as value: `@Local(MyBeanInterface.class)`

Comment: I used this approach successfuly.